# Read from pointer with offset

Tags: c, pointers

I declared a pointer like this

`point *points = malloc(numPoints * sizeof(point));`

how do i assign to pointSend the points pulled from the pointer point.
By supplying offset and numpoint where numpoint is the number of points, offset tells me where to start getting them from

`point *pointsSend = malloc(numPoints[i] * sizeof(point)); pointsSend=/*offset & numpoint`

I haven't found any solution even if I think it's trivial.

Comment: Not entirely clear what you want but, if that's to copy a *block* of `point` elements from `points` to another 'array', then you can use `memcpy`. But remember, `points + n` will inherently incorporate the `sizeof(point)` in its evaluation.

Comment: Or you can use a `for` loop and the `[n]` operator, to copy the required data.

Comment: What do you mean by "the points pulled from the pointer point"? There is no pointer point, and there's no common understanding of what "pulled from" means in C. You use `numPoints[i]` but `numPoints` is I guess a size_t or an int, and not an array.

Comment: *"how do i assign to pointSend the points pulled from the pointer point."* ----> I do not understand what you mean by this.

Comment: Do you mean a simple copy? Such as: `point *points = malloc(numPoints * sizeof(point)); point *pointsSend = malloc(numPoints * sizeof(point)); for (size_t index = 0;  index < numPoints;  ++index) pointsSend[index] = points[index];`

Comment: Or ... Do you want `pointsSend` to be a subsequence of `points`? Such as: `point *points = malloc(numPoints * sizeof(point)); size_t numShort = numPoints - 10; size_t startOff = 5; point *pointsSend = malloc(numShort * sizeof(point)); for (size_t index = 0;  index < numShort;  ++index) pointsSend[index] = points[startOff + index];`

Comment: `points[n]` is the nth `point`. `&points[n]` is the address of the nth `point`. Maybe you want this: `point *pointsSend = &points[n];`.

Comment: Apparently nobody understands your question. You should [edit] any clarify, possibly using translate.goole.com to translate into english.

Comment: This might my an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You should tell us what you're actually trying to achieve, like maybe "write n points starting from offset o info a file"...

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you want.

---

Do you want a copy of a subset of the array pointed by `points`?

```
points
+---------+     +---------+--- ---+---------+---------+----
|       ------->|         |  ...  |         |         |   ...
+---------+     +---------+--- ---+---------+---------+----
                                       |         |
                                      copy      copy
                                       |         |
newpoints                              v         v
+---------+                       +---------+---------+
|       ------------------------->|         |         |
+---------+                       +---------+---------+
```

```c
size_t offset = ...;
size_t n      = ...;

size_t bytes  = n * sizeof( point );

point *newpoints = malloc( bytes );
if ( !newpoints ) {
   ...
}

memcpy( newpoints, points + offset, bytes );

...

free( newpoints );
```

`newpoints[ x ]` is a copy of `points[ x + offset ]`.

---

Or maybe you don't need a copy.

```
points
+---------+     +---------+--- ---+---------+---------+----
|       ------->|         |  ...  |         |         |   ...
+---------+     +---------+--- ---+---------+---------+----
                                       ^
newpoints                              |
+---------+                            |
|       -------------------------------+
+---------+
```

```c
size_t offset = ...;
size_t n      = ...;

point *newpoints = points + offset;

...
```

`newpoints[ x ]` is the same as `points[ x + offset ]`.

For this version, make sure not to free `points` while still using `newpoints`!